# STR_TO_DATE in prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update a date in a table using a prepared statement. The date is in DD/MM/YY format in the form, and so I need to get it into YYYY-MM-DD format for my MySQL database. So I'm trying to use the STR_TO_TIME() function.

However, I can't work out how to include it in my query when using a (procedural) prepared statement, and I can't find any examples online. Can anyone help? Or is there a better way to do it with PHP?

Comment: What you have tried? Add your code

Comment: If you only want to do date-manipulation, don't use mysql for that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DateTime](https://www.php.net/datetime).

```
$date = '07/01/14';

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $date);

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d'); // 2014-01-07
```

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the PHP Documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

**Object oriented style**

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

**Procedural style**

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Comment: I _hate_ the PHP documentation. It may as well be in backwards Ancient Greek for all I can make of it. But thanks anyway :)